# How to get an "interactive" data display in the RStudio Editor?

Tags: r, rstudio

I saw in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=go5Au01Jrvs) that the presenter get's data and plots displayed inside the editor (data frame at 1:27 and plots at 7:05). It does not behave that way in my standard RStudio installation. 
How do I get the same data display?

Comment: Hadley is using a RMarkdown.

Comment: From the Tools menu, select Global Options. Then in the options dialogue, go to the R Markdown tab and check "Show output inline for all R Markdown documents."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is [RMarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) a way for turning "your analyses into high quality documents, reports, presentations and dashboards."

To start a new Markdown project you must go to File, New File, RMarkdown... (install some packages if needed) and select what type of document do you want to create and set a title.

You will get an example default code:

```
---
title: "Title"          #Title of the document
author: "Your name"        
date: "24 de febrero de 2018"
output: pdf_document    #Type of document
---
```

This is called YAML header (where you define your document information and type), and then you have some examples.

To check how to write Rmarkdown reports you can see the [cheet sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf).

The R code must be written inside this lines:

````
```{r}
# R code
```
````

You can run each "chunk" of code (green button placed at right) and output will be displayed as in the video (I think this is the default behaviour. If not, you just need to change te options, click the "tool" button within the chunk (placed at right) and set the configuration you desire.